# AngularJS/Bootstrap modal - event if modal closes via click of the surrounding

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I use the Bootstrap Modal with AngularJS and my question would be if there is an event when modal is closed by clicking at the surroundings of the modal?

```
function showMyModal() {
     var myModal = $modal.open({
        controller: MyController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        size: 'lg',
        windowClass: "modal fade in",
        resolve: {

        }, 
        templateUrl: 'app/myTemplate.modal.html'
        });
    return myModal;

    function MyController( ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation of the ui.bootstrap o Modal you can have the promise when the dialog dismiss or close, so you can do stuff.

```
myModal.result.then(function (response) {
  $log.info(response); 
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

this event are triggering by the

```
$uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
```

and

```
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
```